# Canvas - getWidth(), getHeight() e OnClickListener()

Tags: android, canvas

Estou fazendo um aplicativo para Android utilizando a classe Canvas, mas estou com alguns problemas.

1º. Ao executar os métodos abaixo,

```
canvas.drawText("Width: " + fotoOriginal.getWidth(), 0, 10, paint);
canvas.drawText("Height: " + fotoOriginal.getHeight(), 0, 20, paint);
```

eu vejo na tela: "Width: 1580" e "Height: 977", ou seja, minha foto tem 1580 x 977 px.

Porém quando eu tento escrever na tela a razão da largura pela altura,

```
myRatio = fotoOriginal.getWidth() / fotoOriginal.getHeight();
canvas.drawText("Ratio is: " + myRatio, 0, 30, paint);
```

o resultado que aparece na tela é 1.0 . Não importa o que eu faça, o resultado é sempre 1 ou 0. **Por que não aparece a real razão da imagem, ou seja, 1,617...?**

2º. Como falei, os métodos getWidth() e getHeight() me retornam 1580 e 977, respectivamente, mas quando eu vou no arquivo da foto e deixo o mouse em cima dela, aparece "Dimensões: 1053 x 651", a mesma dimensão que aparece no Paint. **Por quê existe a diferença de dimensão?**

3°. Qual a maneira mais correta (e aonde) de eu adicionar o OnClickListener(), para por exemplo desenhar qualquer coisa no Canvas quando um usuário clicar na tela?

Segue o código:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

public int teste = 0;

DrawView drawView;

public static int width;
public static int height;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Para a activity pegar a tela inteira
    fullscreen();

    // Para saber o tamanho da tela
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    width = size.x;
    height = size.y;

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Screen size is: " + width + " px (X), and " + height + "px (Y)!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // DrawView
    drawView = new DrawView(this);
    drawView.setOnClickListener(new HeyClick());
    drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    setContentView(drawView);

}

public void fullscreen(){

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

}

public class HeyClick implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + teste, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        teste++;

    }

}

}
```

A outra classe:

```
public class DrawView extends View{

Paint paint = new Paint();

int x = MyActivity.width;
int y = MyActivity.height;

Bitmap fotoOriginal;
Bitmap fotoScaled;
float myRatio;


public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    fotoOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ilha_de_malaga_transparente);
    fotoScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fotoOriginal, x, y, false);

    myRatio = fotoOriginal.getWidth() / fotoOriginal.getHeight();

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawBitmap(fotoScaled,0,0, paint);
    canvas.drawText("Width: " + fotoOriginal.getWidth(), 0, 10, paint);
    canvas.drawText("Height: " + fotoOriginal.getHeight(), 0, 20, paint);
    canvas.drawText("Ratio is: " + myRatio, 0, 30, paint);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema na verdade é que você está dividindo dois inteiros e o resultado acaba sendo outro inteiro.

Você pode fazer o cast de um dos operadores pra `float` que o resultado da divisão também será um float.

```
myRatio = (float)fotoOriginal.getWidth() / fotoOriginal.getHeight();
```

Caso queira mostrar apenas duas casas decimais você pode usar `String.format`

```
canvas.drawText(String.format("Ratio is: %.2f", myRatio), 0, 30, paint);
```